# how to name matrix columns

Tags: dataframe, matrix, naming

I have a matrix like below, how can I give the column names like "month", "2015", "2016, "2017" from column 2:5? Thank you.

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] 
 [1,] ""   "1"  "75" "75" "94" 
 [2,] ""   "2"  "77" "67" "69" 
 [3,] ""   "3"  "67" "78" "80" 
 [4,] ""   "4"  "71" "99" "84" 
 [5,] ""   "5"  "62" "89" "74"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using R, you could do something like this (for matrix `M`)

```
colnames(M) <- c("","month","2015","2016","2017")
```